# NAudio crash on x86 code

Tags: c#, x86, naudio

Like in subject, everything works fine in `AnyCPU`, but when I change to `x86` -> application crash. I work under Win 7 x64.

Edit:

```
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))"}
```

Stack:

```
   at System.StubHelpers.InterfaceMarshaler.ConvertToManaged(IntPtr pUnk, IntPtr itfMT, IntPtr classMT, Int32 flags)  
   at NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut.IDirectSound.CreateSoundBuffer(BufferDescription desc, Object& dsDSoundBuffer, IntPtr pUnkOuter)  
   at NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut.InitializeDirectSound()  
   at NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut.PlaybackThreadFunc()  
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)  
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)  
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)  
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Without any details about the code or the crash it's impossible to offer any advice.

Comment: Sry, I thoguht it's configuration issue. However, I added error message. Also I checked it @ Windows Xp in VirtualBox, and it works fine in 32 bit mode.

Answer (score 1):

Strange, the only input parameter of note is the buffer description (an instance of `DSBUFFERDESC`), but I can't see any x64/x86 issues with the NAudio interop for it. Maybe some of the secondary buffer flags aren't supported on your device:

```
bufferDesc2.dwFlags = DirectSoundBufferCaps.DSBCAPS_GETCURRENTPOSITION2
    | DirectSoundBufferCaps.DSBCAPS_CTRLPOSITIONNOTIFY
    | DirectSoundBufferCaps.DSBCAPS_GLOBALFOCUS
    | DirectSoundBufferCaps.DSBCAPS_CTRLVOLUME
    | DirectSoundBufferCaps.DSBCAPS_STICKYFOCUS;
```

The other odd thing about the stack trace is that the error is in `ConvertToManaged`, which suggests that it is the conversion of the sound buffer to a managed object which is going wrong, but I can't think why that would happen, as we don't try to cast to `IDirectSoundBuffer` until after the call to `CreateSoundBuffer` completes.

Any reason why your app can't use WaveOut or WaveOutEvent instead? You might find them more reliable.

Comment: My application uses WaveOut (not event version), DirecSound, ASIO and WASAPI. However ASIO and WASAPI crashes application after random calls to stop/play. Anyway I dont understand your answer, too complicated for me. +1